# Почему не обновляется стейт в SPA

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, state

в реакте относительно недавно, делаю SPA, на одной из страниц, почему то не обновляется state.
При этом в других местах приложения все окей с такого вида запросами и их обработкой.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { main } from "../api/api";

const Test = () => {
    let { title } = useParams();

    const [ getData, setData ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        main.getPokywat(title).then( data => {
            console.log(data); // тут данные есть
            setData (data); // тут их присваиваю
            console.log(getData); // и нет их в итоге
        })

    }, []);

    return (
        <></>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменение стейта асинхронное действие. Т.ч. после вызова setData он может не измениться...
Тгда getData вернет данные "старого" стейта, который еще не успел измениться.

Comment: самый распространенный случай для новичков)
используйте данные не из state если хотите их обновить/использовать сразу после получения